# How can I work side by side between Python and R in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code?

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I would like to work between programming languages when using a notebook but the R option does not appear in the list of languages, is there a way to add R to the sidebar?
[image: on the right hand side it gives me the option to select other languages and insert]

[image: It gives me language options but not R.]

Comment: Can this [document](https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/jupyter_r_notebooks.html#Setting-Up-R-with-Jupyter) help?